# Prove the formula $\sigma^2(1+x^T_{n+1}(X^TX)^{-1}x_{n+1}+\sigma^2_u \cdot\mathrm{tr}((X^TX)^{-1}))+\sigma^2_u\beta^T\beta$ for the variance of error

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, expected-value, predictor, measurement-error

Suppose we have a model $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$, where $y$ is an $n\times 1$ vector, $X$ is an $n\times k$ matrix of parameters of full rank $k$, $\beta$ is a $k\times 1$ vector and $\varepsilon$ is an $n\times 1$ vector such that $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\varepsilon)=\vec{0}$ and $\mathop{\mathbb{Var}}(\varepsilon)=\sigma^2I_n$. We then can construct the OLS estimate $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. 
 Now suppose we wish to predict the value $y_{n+1}=x^T_{n+1}\beta+\varepsilon_{n+1}$, where $x_{n+1}=(1,x_{n+1,2},...,x_{n+1,k})^T$ and $\varepsilon_{n+1}$ is independent of $\varepsilon$ and has zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. However we observe the vector $x_{n+1}$ with some eror: $z=x_{n+1}+u$, here $u$ is a random vector independent of both $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon_{n+1}$ with $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(u)=\vec{0}$ and $\mathop{\mathbb{Var}}(u)=\sigma^2_uI_k$ 
We use the predictor $\hat{y}=z^T\hat{\beta}$ and wish to compute the variance of the prediction error. It is quite obvious that $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(y_{n+1}-\hat{y})=0$, so to compute variance we only need to evaluate
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[(y_{n+1}-\hat{y})^2\right]=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[(x^T_{n+1}\beta+\varepsilon_{n+1}-z^T\hat{\beta})^2\right]=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left[(x^T_{n+1}\beta+\varepsilon_{n+1}-(x^T_{n+1}+u^T)\hat{\beta})^2\right]=
\mathop{\mathbb{E}\left[(x^T_{n+1}(\beta-\hat{\beta})+\varepsilon_{n+1}-u^T\hat{\beta})^2\right]}=
\mathop{\mathbb{E}([x^T_{n+1}(\beta-\hat{\beta})(\beta-\hat{\beta})^Tx_{n+1}+2x^T_{n+1}(\beta-\hat{\beta})\varepsilon_{n+1}+\varepsilon^2_{n+1}]-2(x^T_{n+1}(\beta-\hat{\beta})+\varepsilon_{n+1})u^T\hat{\beta}+\hat{\beta}^Tuu^T\hat{\beta})}$$
Previously, I have calculated that the expected value of whatever is in brackets $[\cdot]$ to be $\sigma^2(1+x^T_{n+1}(X^TX)^{-1}x_{n+1})$ and clearly due to the independence of $u$ and $\hat{\beta}$ we get $\mathop{\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta}^Tuu^T\hat{\beta})=\sigma^2_u\beta^T\beta}$, so what is left to compute is
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}(-2(x^T_{n+1}(\beta-\hat{\beta})+\varepsilon_{n+1})u^T\hat{\beta})}=\mathop{\mathbb{E}(-2(x^T_{n+1}(\beta-\hat{\beta})u^T\hat{\beta}+\varepsilon_{n+1}u^T\hat{\beta}))}=\mathop{\mathbb{E}(-2x^T_{n+1}\beta u^T\hat{\beta}+2x^T_{n+1}\hat{\beta}u^T\hat{\beta}-2\varepsilon_{n+1}u^T\hat{\beta})}=2\mathop{\mathbb{E}(x^T_{n+1}\hat{\beta}\hat{\beta}^T u)}$$

The final answer should be $\sigma^2(1+x^T_{n+1}(X^TX)^{-1}x_{n+1}+\sigma^2_u \cdot\mathrm{tr}((X^TX)^{-1}))+\sigma^2_u\beta^T\beta$. So, this expectation should evaluate to $\sigma^2\sigma^2_u \cdot\mathrm{tr}((X^TX)^{-1})$, however, I do not see how that can be achieved. It seems to me that the expectation should equal zero, since it contains the multiplication by $u$ and it is independent of every other random variable/vector. How do you arrive at the final result? Did I make a mistake in my derivation?

**Edit:** I figured out that actually
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta}^Tuu^T\hat{\beta})}=\mathop{\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\beta}^Tu)^2]=\mathop{\mathbb{Var}(\hat{\beta}^Tu)}}=\sum_{t=1}^{k}\mathop{\mathbb{Var}(\hat{\beta}_{t}u_{t})}=\sigma^2\sigma^2_u \cdot\mathrm{tr}((X^TX)^{-1})$$
Since $\mathop{\mathbb{Var}(\hat{\beta})}=\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$, the sum of variances of betas will be exactly $\sigma^2\cdot\mathrm{tr}((X^TX)^{-1})$. However, now I don't get where the term $\sigma^2_u\beta^T\beta$ comes from

Comment: Your last edit is still not right when you change from the expectation of a squared value to the variance. $E[X^2] = E[X]^2+VAR[X]$

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I know, but this expected value $\mathop{\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta}^Tu)}=\sum_{t=1}^{k}\mathop{\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta}_t u_t)}=\sum_{t=1}^{k}\mathop{\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta}_t)}\mathop{\mathbb{E}(u_t)}=0$, that is why I omitted it

Comment: you are right, that was not where the error was made. It is in your expression for $\mathop{\mathbb{Var}(\hat{\beta}^Tu)}$, does it approach zero when the variance of $\hat\beta$ approaches zero? Think of the equation for Var(UV) that I gave in my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Ivan Just out of curiosity: Is this exercise/solution from a particular textbook?

Comment: @statmerkur The exercise is from a Russian textbook 'Magnus, Katyshev, Peresetsky. Econometrics. Introductory Course: A Textbook, 6th edition, 2004', I am not sure that there is a translation, so that might not be useful. The textbook doesn't provide a solution for this exercise, so I tried to come up with my own

Comment: @Mr.Ivan Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [Sextus Empiricus' assertion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/594911/136579) that your calculation of the expectation of
$\left(\hat\beta^\top u u^\top\hat\beta\right)$ is wrong.
I get
$$
\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left(\hat\beta^\top u u^\top\hat\beta\right)
&=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left(\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\hat\beta^\top u u^\top\hat\beta\right)\right)\\
&=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left(\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\hat\beta\hat\beta^\top u u^\top\right)\right)\\
&=\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left(\hat\beta\hat\beta^\top u u^\top\right)\right)\\
&=\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left(\hat\beta\hat\beta^\top\right)\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left( u u^\top\right)\right)\\
&=\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left\{\left[\mathop{\mathbb{V}}\left(\hat\beta\right)+\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left(\hat\beta\right)\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left(\hat\beta\right)^\top\right]\left[\mathop{\mathbb{V}}\left(u\right)+\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left(u\right)\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left(u\right)^\top\right]\right\}\\
&=\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left\{\left[\sigma^2\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1}+\beta\beta^\top\right]\sigma_u^2I_k\right\}\\
&=\sigma^2\sigma_u^2\cdot\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1}\right) +
\sigma_u^2\cdot\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\beta\beta^\top\right)\\
&=\sigma^2\sigma_u^2\cdot\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1}\right) +
\sigma_u^2\beta^\top \beta.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a product of variables with variance. For this you need get something like the standard rule

$$\text{Var}(UV) = \text{Var}(U)\text{Var}(V) + E(U)^2\text{Var}(V) + \text{Var}(U)E(V)^2$$

This term $\sigma^2\sigma^2_u \cdot\mathrm{tr}((X^TX)^{-1})$ relates to the product part $\text{Var}(U)\text{Var}(V)$.

---

Tracing back your equations to see where this product term must come from, it seems to me like the following is not right $\mathop{\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta}^Tuu^T\hat{\beta})=\sigma^2_u\beta^T\beta}$.